# Can't find jquery-ui in rails engine (jquery-rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline

I'm using the jquery-rails gem.
In a rails (non-mountable) engine I have in
app/assets/javascripts/my_engine/application.js.erb:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.min
```

And I get the error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui.min'\n  (in /home/me/rails/my_engine/app/assets/javascripts/my_engine/application.js.erb
```

The same set up was working fine in the container application. How is it that the manifest can find jquery and jquery_ujs but not jquery-ui.min?

I have the jquery-rails gem in my container app's Gemfile, in the engine's gemspec and in the engine's Gemfile and ran bundle install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using version 3.0.0 or newer of jquery-rails, jQuery UI has been removed from the gem.

See [commit 2fdcdb2633cbc6426d412c050200fc31d14b9a3b](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/commit/2fdcdb2633cbc6426d412c050200fc31d14b9a3b).

It looks like the creators of jquery-rails recommend taking a look at the [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem if you still need jQuery UI in your app.

Comment: By default the new version of rails 3.0+ will include jquery-ui by default which is why they removed the gem.

Comment: Do I need both gems and then //= require jquery and
//= require jquery.ui.all in the manifest?

Comment: Yes it's working by including both gems in the engine's gemspec, Gemfile and both requires in the manifest

Comment: Thanks - this helped me, the only gotcha was that I had to refer to "jquery.ui.all" in manifest (not "jquery-ui" as I was first doing).

Answer (score 1):

To use jquery.ui.all  you need to add following gem in to your gemfile, not it is seprated from jquery_rails.

gem "jquery-ui-rails", "~> 4.0.5"

use following in your application.js to access

//= require jquery.ui.all

Best luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's new syntax to include jquery ui.

Use `//= require jquery.ui.all` to include all modules, or you could specify just the core with `//= require jquery.ui.core`

more info at [jquery-ui-rails gem page](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)